# How to install Julia kernel for Jupyterhub

Tags: julia, jupyterhub

I'm trying to make julia language available through jupyterhub on an ubuntu server.
I already have installed and configured the jupyterhub. Its working fine with python3.5.
And the authentication method is Regular Unix users and PAM.

I installed the julia language in `/usr/local/julia-1.0.2/` and it is available for all users globally.

then with the root user I set the `JULIA_DEPOT_PATH="/usr/share/juliapackages/` 
then again with the root user, I run the julia and run the
`using Pkg
Pkg.add("IJulia")`
 
it installs the IJulia in the specified path.

from this point, I didn't find any further useful instructions on the internet over the subject of installing julia kernel for jupyterhub, so I don't know how to proceed.
does anybody have a good step by step document to find the solution?

I followed the instruction proposed [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/julia-kernel-on-jupyterhub-system-wide-ldap/14809) but it seems doesn't work for me.

Comment: Whats the error? AFAIK the julia kernel will be installed as part of `Pkg.build("IJulia")`, which should be automatically run when you `Pkg.add` it.

Comment: when logging in a user it start the notebook but julia is not one of Its kernels.

Comment: @fredrikekre The error is  [Run `import Pkg; Pkg.add("IJulia")` to install the IJulia package.]

Comment: Ok, that would have been useful to include from the start that the problem is that the package is not found. Firstly check that you have also set `DEPOT_PATH` correctly for the users, and secondly, just because a package source files exist in the `DEPOT_PATH` it does not mean that the package is available to `using`, it needs to be found somewhere in the `LOAD_PATH` too. See my second suggestion here: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/30528#issuecomment-451398246

Answer (score -1):

As you are using Jupyterhub, the best way would be to use a docker spawner and use the data science docker image which has Julia already installed and configured.

https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/blob/master/datascience-notebook/Dockerfile

Comment: unfortunately, the department policy is to not using the docker. So that's not an option for me. but thanks for the help.